# Could `impliant` be a proper word, meaning opposite of `pliant`?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, is-it-a-word

We have the word *impliable* meaning the opposite of *pliable,* but there is no dictionary opposite of *pliant*. (Shorter OED, Apple Dictionary on Mac, dictionary.reference.com, www.merriam‑webster.com)

Could *impliant* be acceptable under certain circumstances, such as in a literary or poetic context?

Note: according to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44673/what-is-the-difference-between-pliable-and-pliant), *pliant* and *pliable* are synonyms.

---

My online searching would have been more successful, if I'd realised that I'd been redirected to `define implant`, and that there was a subtle link to actually search for `define impliant`.

Having said that, I still wouldn't have found *unpliant* as a plausible answer.

Comment: Poetic license gives one fair broad freedoms. Beware that that you don't use this word in a context where it could be misread or confused with "implant" on a quick scan or casual reading.

Comment: While there are plenty of uses of _impliant_ to be found in Google Books the more common word is _unpliant_ . http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unpliant

Comment: Not grokking the downvote. You could have at least left a comment ...

Comment: I don't really get the two downvotes (and three close votes either). _unpliant_ is not really a common word but it is better documented than _impliant_ and yet it doesn't appear in the half-dozen thesaurus type sites I just checked as an antonym for _pliant_. Maybe your question just seems too simple on the outside.

Comment: Will do, but it'll be tomorrow.

Comment: In normal speech/writing I would tend to use "rigid".  In poetry use whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing up and posting everything below the double lines, I found this.

[image: Langenscheidt's Thesaurus entry for Pliant]

From *Langensheidt's Pocket Merriam-Webster, Dictionary of Synonyms and Antonyms, 1998* [Google Books (snippet)](https://books.google.com/books?id=pf_AL0eIfs8C&q=impliant&dq=impliant&hl=en&sa=X&ei=c9PmVOmZK821uASaqoCIDA&redir_esc=y)

---

---

> [OED]**Pliant**
>   1. Bending; capable of being bent or folded with ease; supple, lithe, flexible
>   *from the 14th century onward*

Antonyms of *pliant* from Thesaurus.com, Merriam-Webster.com, Synonyms.com and a number of other common thesaurus sites offered:

> stiff, rigid, inflexible, intractable, unadaptable and a few others.

Not one of the common thesaurus sites offered the most obvious antonym of *pliant* which is *unpliant*

> [OED]**Unpliant**
>   1 Not bending readily or easily; stiff.
>   *from the 17th century onward*

The *un-* prefix expresses negation, but so does the *im-* prefix, particularly before the letters b, m and p and there's no doubt that *pliant* starts with *p*.
So why is *impliant* not in any dictionaries (apart from Burton's Legal Thesaurus 4th Ed. which only mentions it as [a synonym of unyielding](https://books.google.com/books?id=9OGU6qOu_3YC&q=impliant&dq=impliant&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6dbmVMLxBYapuwSevICgCQ&redir_esc=y) but in the [5th Ed. it gets it's own mention](https://books.google.com/books?id=-cv0AAAAQBAJ&q=impliant&dq=impliant&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6dbmVMLxBYapuwSevICgCQ&redir_esc=y) with unyielding as it's synonym)?
It's hard to tell really, there's plenty of usage for *impliant* to be found in Google Books (mostly 18th century but some modern ones too).

> *London Magazine, Vol.24, 1755 in a section about 'Observations on grafting'* [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=gFQDAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA419&dq=impliant&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rszmVJ7nO5eeugSW_IGwAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=impliant&f=false)
>   ...either in the wood already formed, and which then ceases to be supple, or in the gross bark, which is altogether as impliant as the wood.
>
> *Lectures to working men, Rev. Arthur Mursell, 1859* [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=3ikCAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA147&dq=impliant&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fdHmVK7UBYODuwTgr4LABQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=impliant&f=false)
>   The stubborn clay which was tough and impliant in the woman's hands, may be moulded at pleasure by the fingers of the child.
>
> *The John Dewey Society Lectureship Series, v5, 1962* [Google Books (snippet)](https://books.google.com/books?id=NDUrAQAAMAAJ&q=impliant&dq=impliant&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NtPmVKjNE4fIuATvjoDYCw&redir_esc=y)
>   ... sculptors who left even upon such impliant clay as mine the delicate chiseling of refined genius, ...
>
> *Cruise Control, Victoria Jenkins, 2002* [Google Books (snippet)](https://books.google.com/books?id=cwYVsMDjuNIC&q=impliant&dq=impliant&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6dbmVMLxBYapuwSevICgCQ&redir_esc=y)
>   A couple of glasses of late harvest chardonnay to help dissolve the unacceptable impliant crust of the banana-peach tart ...

While I was looking for these uses of *impliant* one thing became quite clear, *impliant* appears in a number of French-to-English dictionaries so perhaps it was always thought of as a French word that was trying to become assimilated into English but never quite made it, because we already have *unpliant*. I am genuinely surprised, given the number of uses *impliant* has had in the last half millenium that it's not listed in the OED at all, not even as *erroneous* or *rare*.

All in all, *impliant* is a perfectly good word that obviously means *not pliant*, however the more common term is *unpliant*. The surprising thing about *unpliant* is that I have not found a single reference that mentions it as an antonym of *pliant*.

Comment: You should send the citations to the OED and ask that they include _impliant_. They have both _impliable_ and _unpliant_, so they should have both _impliant_ and _unpliant_ as well.

Comment: This is just an awesome++ answer! Far more knowledge and research than I was expecting!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Done.

Answer (score 3):

In legal speak, **impliant: unyielding, inflexible** see, the Free Dictionary.

Comment: +1 The usually preferred approach is to provide a link to the online dictionary.

Comment: Is there some `english.stackexchange` etiquette I've missed here? Several dictionaries are available online. I'm not sure which one would be "the" one.

Comment: Hi, Stewart, I'm rather a newcomer myself, but any question that can be answered by a quick google is usually closed as GR or general reference, which is how I found the answer I submitted. I, too, was unfamiliar with the word. You did nothing wrong. :-)

Comment: I did do "a quick google". I didn't find your reference, and none of the other dictionaries I have, either on or off-line helped me. (I understand not wanting "numpty" questions, but on the other hand, there's a certain minimum knowledge here which I don't appear to have, and which nobody is linking me to.)

Comment: I've had a look at both those links. They didn't contain anything which surprised me. I still don't get what, specifically, is wrong with my question. Could someone please be clear and exact in informing me?

Comment: @Stewart - Does Frank comment answer your question?

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, Frank's comment is a good candidate answer

Comment: @Stewart There is no one dictionary that is the standard (although some would argue for the Oxford English Dictionary, print version, often referred to as *OED*). A good place to start is *onelook.com*. It is a portal to many dictionaries. You insert your term and it lists and links to dictionaries that have a definition.

Comment: @Stewart - that shows that the information you are looking for is available in online dictionaries..which you can easily have access to. If the information you can find in the General Reference is not clear to you or if you have more queries you can then Ask a Question here.

Comment: @Josh61 - Er, sorry, you're saying that Frank's comment shows I should have been able to look up the knowledge he imparted by myself? I disagree. I don't see that connection at all.

Comment: @bib - I am indeed the proud owner of the OED, in both print and digital form, as well as the Shorter and Concise versions. I also searched online, but I didn't know about onelook.com. Should there be a "search here first" section under Help or Tour?

Comment: @Stewart Suggest it on ELU Meta.